# how to print double exactly as input in C

Tags: c, double

In c language,
for example:

if value double x = 3.4900

I want output be 3.4900, not 3.490000

The problem is the input value x is changeable, I don't how many decimal point will be.

any idea?

Comment: You can specify the number of digits after the decimal point in the `printf()` format string. `%.4f` will print 4 digits after.

Comment: printf("%.4f", x);  -> You can specify the decimal place in the printf() statement

Comment: There are  numbers with surprisingly few decimal places in decimal representation, which cannot be stored precisely in a float or even double value. Your expectation to be able to output any value as given in code or in input is unreliable, even with the methods to control decimal places as in the answers below. Please define in your question whether you only want help with the specific given example or whether you need a method for any input value. Because for the latter, the answer is "You can't." Search for "float broken".

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken (not actually proposing as duplicate, because question would be closed immediatly....).

Comment: If the expected values are small enough, precision can be gained by using integer types to work in multiples of the units actually wanted. This is often suggested for problems involving money. Rather than using a floating point type, use an integer type to store cents or even hundredths or thousands of cents. For instance, four dollars might be stored  as `400` rather than `4.00`.

Answer (score 1):

to make an answer:

```
double x = 3.4900;

printf("the value of x is %.4f",x);
```

`.4` means, you print the value with for digits after the dot. If you want to print exact and changeable number of digits you read in, you had to work with a string.

Answer (score 1):

`double x = 3.4900;` is exactly the same as `double x = 3.49;`

When you ask about "input", you might mean "reading a value as a string from a file or stdin"... You could count the digits to the right of the decimal point and store that count in another variable.

Once that string is converted to `double`, there is no record of how much 'precision' was supplied by the source.

And, because `floats` and `doubles` use base-2 numbers (not base-10), it is extremely rare that the internal representation matches the base-10 version (without some rounding involved.)

Note in the following the 'extra effort' to determine the `precision` from the pseudo-input string...

```
int main() {
    char *s1 = "3.4900";
    char *s2 = "3.49";

    double d1 = strtod( s1, NULL );
    double d2 = strtod( s2, NULL );

    printf( "%s\n", d1 == d2 ? "Same" : "Diff!!" );

    char *cp = strchr( s1, '.' ) + 1;
    int prec = strlen( s1 ) - (cp - s1);
    printf( "s1 restores as %.*lf\n", prec, d1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> any idea?

C programming language does not have reflection - it's not possible to inspect itself. If you want to have the ability to inspect the source code of a C program from that C program itself, you have to implement such functionality yourself.

> how to print double exactly as input in C

You have to include verbatim the stringifed form of the input inside your source code and print that.

```
double x = 3.4900;
const char *xstr = "3.4900";
printf("source code %s was translated into %f\n", xstr, x);
```

With the help of `#` preprocessor operator, we could make it a bit nicer and don't repeat ourselves:

```
struct double_and_string {
   double x;
   const char *str;
};
#define VAL_AND_STR(x)   { x, #x }
struct double_and_string a = VAL_AND_STR(3.4900);
printf("source code %s was translated into %f\n", a.str, a.x);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
double x = 3.4900;

printf("the value of x is %lf",x);
```

Comment: This will give an output with 6 decimal places